# Run docker commands from gitlab-ci

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, docker-in-docker

I have this gitlab-ci file:

```
services:
  - docker:18.09.7-dind
variables:
  SONAR_TOKEN: "$PROJECT_SONAR_TOKEN"
  GIT_DEPTH: 0
  MAVEN_CLI_OPTS: "-s .m2/settings.xml --batch-mode"
  MAVEN_OPTS: "-Dmaven.repo.local=.m2/repository"

  DOCKER_HOST: "tcp://docker:2375"
  DOCKER_DRIVER: overlay2

sonarqube-check:
  image: maven:latest
  stage: test
  before_script:
    - "docker version"
    - "mkdir $PWD/.m2"
    - "cp -f /cache/settings.xml $PWD/.m2/settings.xml"
  script:
    - mvn $MAVEN_CLI_OPTS clean verify sonar:sonar -Dsonar.qualitygate.wait=true -Dsonar.login=$SONAR_TOKEN -Dsonar.projectKey="project-key"
  after_script:
    - "rm -rf $PWD/.m2"
  allow_failure: false
  only:
    - merge_requests
```

For some reason docker in docker service does not find the binaries for docker (the *docker version* command, line 16):

```
/bin/bash: line 111: docker: command not found
```

I'm wondering if there is a way of doing this inside of the gitlab-ci file because I need to run docker for the tests, if there is an image that contains both maven and docker binaries or if I'll have to create my own docker image.

It has to be all in one stage, I cannot divide it in two stages (or at least I don't know how to compile in maven in one stage and run the tests witha  docker image in another stage)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you correctly pointed out. You need `mvn` and `docker` binaries in the image you are using for that GitLab-CI job.

The quickest win is probably to install docker in your `maven:latest` build image during run time in the `before_script` section.

```
before_script:
    - apt-get update && apt-get install -y docker.io
    - docker version
```

If that's slowing down your job too much you might want to build your own custom docker image that contains both Maven and Docker.

Also have a look at the [article about `dind` on Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/releases/2019/07/31/docker-in-docker-with-docker-19-dot-03/) if you end up moving to Docker 19.03+